# Not getting result from Mio poll

Tags: asynchronous, rust, mio

I've built a basic runtime using `smol` with `flume` as the queue and `futures_lite` for the blocking of tasks until they are complete. I am now trying to get `Mio` polling directly in the `poll` function of a standard `Future`. However, when I run a TCP listener with `Mio` all in the main function it works fine. However, when I try and put the `Mio` TCP polling in the `poll` function of a `Future` I get the printout that there is not events every 5 seconds meaning that the future is being put back on the task queue to be polled again. However, when I send a data packet over TCP, the no events printout happens instantly and the client does not error. This means that the data is being sent to the socket but the `Mio` polling just doesn't seem to yield any data from the socket. Below is the code of the future:

```rust
use mio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use mio::{Events, Interest, Poll as MioPoll, Token};
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::error::Error;

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

const SERVER: Token = Token(0);

struct ServerWorker {
    server: TcpListener,
    poll: MioPoll,
}


impl ServerWorker {

    pub fn new() -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let addr = "127.0.0.1:13265".parse()?;
        let mut server = TcpListener::bind(addr)?;
        let poll: MioPoll = MioPoll::new()?;
        poll.registry()
        .register(&mut server, SERVER, Interest::READABLE)?;
        Ok(ServerWorker{
            server,
            poll,
        })
    }
}

impl Future for ServerWorker {
    type Output = String;


    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) 
        -> Poll<Self::Output> {

        let mut events = Events::with_capacity(128);

        let outcome = self.poll.poll(
            &mut events, 
            Some(Duration::from_secs(5))
        ).unwrap();

        println!("outcome: {:?}", outcome);

        if outcome == () {
            println!("no events");
            cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
            return Poll::Pending
        }

        println!("events: {:?}", events);
        for event in events.iter() {
            println!("event: {:?}", event);
            match event.token() {
                SERVER => {
                    let (mut stream, _) = self.server.accept().unwrap();
                    let mut received_data = [0; 4096];
                    let bytes_read = 0;
                    let _ = stream.read(&mut received_data[bytes_read..]);
                    let received_data_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&received_data).to_string();
                    return Poll::Ready(received_data_string)
                }
                // We don't expect any events with tokens other than those we provided.
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        }
        cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
        return Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

I appreciate that there are better ways run a server but I'm just looking into this approach. I've read about a `Mio` waker [here](https://docs.rs/mio/latest/mio/struct.Waker.html) but calling this doesn't seem to work, through, I think it's important as the `Mio` waker talks about polling over threads and futures do pass through threads. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm awaiting the future in the main function as seen below:

```rust
fn main() {
    Runtime::new().with_low_num(2).with_high_num(4).run();

    let server_worker = ServerWorker::new().unwrap();
    let test = spawn_task!(server_worker);
    let _outcome = future::block_on(test);
}
```

I then just call the TCP socket from a python script for testing (this script works when the `Mio` TCP listener is just running in the `main`). And the `spawn_task!` macro is just a wrapper around a structure simular to the following:

```rust
pub fn spawn_task<F, T>(future: F) -> Task<T>
where
    F: Future<Output = T> + Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
{
    static QUEUE: Lazy<flume::Sender<Runnable>> = Lazy::new(|| {
        let (tx, rx) = flume::unbounded::<Runnable>();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(runnable) = rx.recv() {
                let _ = catch_unwind(|| runnable.run());
            }
        });
        tx

    });

    let schedule = |runnable| QUEUE.send(runnable).unwrap();
    let (runnable, task) = async_task::spawn(future, schedule);

    runnable.schedule();
    return task
}
```

I'm not putting in all the task stealing and multiple threads otherwise it would just bloat the question but the runtime works on a lot of other tasks.

Comment: Where are awaiting the poll future?

Comment: @AhmedMasud thanks for the response I have updated the question to include the code of where the future is waited on

Comment: If the poll succeeds it will return a `Ok(())` since you unwrap it the type of outcome will be `()` on success. On the other hand you will be returning `Poll::Pending`. I think that might be the problem. Here is the doc https://docs.rs/mio/latest/mio/struct.Poll.html

Comment: you are not `awaiting` the `catch_unwind` (I assume this is from the futures crate). Don't use the panic::catch_unwind, it's better to use FutureExt::catch_undwind (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159442/how-do-i-use-paniccatch-unwind-with-asynchronous-code)